# How to process wierd JSON using C#

Tags: c#, json

I have JSON like

```
string fields = "{'foo':'{\'Resources\':{\'resourceUri\':\'/xf/b/rs/RA-a-675e/fo/age/s/m78\',\'location\':\'us\',\'tags\':{\'displayName\':\'A's storage\',\'container.registry\':\'dd\'}}}'}";
```

Unfortunately, I cannot change above JSON

```
var customDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(fields);
```

Always throws an exception. Why?

Comment: As far as I can tell that is not valid JSON.  Key names, as far as I know, can not contain apostrophes.

Comment: You could try pre-processing the string.. but I'd do everything in my power to ensure valid inputs to the system before I started kludging together workarounds.

Comment: Double quote keys and values `{"key":"value"}`.
Escape double quotes and backslashes when used in a C# string `string val = "{\"key\":\"val\"}";`.

Comment: May it help [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T98Ml1)

Comment: Just to confirm - you're really receiving JSON with property names and values that are surrounded by single quotes rather than double quotes -- and in addition some of the property values are strings that contain embedded non-escaped single quotes?  Or did you modify the JSON somehow in creating your c# string literal?

Answer (score 2):

This JSON is not just a simple `Dictionary<string, string>`!  It is a custom type like below:

JSON:

```
{foo:{Resources:{resourceUri:"/xf/b/rs/RA-a-675e/fo/age/s/m78",location:"us",tags:{displayName:"As storage",containerregistry:"dd"}}}}
```

C# classes:

```
public class Tags
{
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public string containerregistry { get; set; }
}

public class Resources
{
    public string resourceUri { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public Tags tags { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public Resources Resources { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public Foo foo { get; set; }
}
```

After that you can deserialize:

```
var customObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(fields);
```

Comment: The values inside the JSON can change. So cannot have a concrete class to deserialize. Here is another example: {'region':'US','service':'Store','Type':'','Name':'Kitt's Service'}. Look at "kitt's" which is screwing the JSON

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse this JSON string as a `Dictionary<string, string>`, you could replace every `\` with `\\`, and replace `A's storage` with `A\\'s storage`. After replacing, the input string becomes like this:

```
string fields = "{'foo':'{\\'Resources\\':{\\'resourceUri\\':\\'/xf/b/rs/RA-a-675e/fo/age/s/m78\\',\\'location\\':\\'us\\',\\'tags\\':{\\'displayName\\':\\'A\\'s storage\\',\\'container.registry\\':\\'dd\\'}}}'}";
```

Then when you call:

```
var customDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(fields);
```

`customDict` will contain only one key-value pair:

```
customDict["foo"] == "{'Resources':{'resourceUri':'/xf/b/rs/RA-a-675e/fo/age/s/m78','location':'us','tags':{'displayName':'A's storage','container.registry':'dd'}}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but something is wrong with your json string. Anyway I assume this is your fixed json string

```
string jsonString = "{'foo':{'Resources':{'resourceUri':'/xf/b/rs/RA-a-675e/fo/age/s/m78','location':'us','tags':{'displayName':'As storage','containerregistry':'dd'}}}}";
```

with `Manage Nuget Packages` install `Newtonsoft.Json` for your project then use these `POCO` classes for your json string

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Foo foo { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public Resources Resources { get; set; }
}

public class Resources
{
    public string resourceUri { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public Tags tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tags
{
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public string containerregistry { get; set; }
}
```

now you can deserialize your json string into a C# object

```
var deserializedRootObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonString);

System.Console.WriteLine(deserializedRootObject.foo.Resources.location); // us
```

---

Here is a complete console application example

```
namespace JsonDEMO
{
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Foo foo { get; set; }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public Resources Resources { get; set; }
    }

    public class Resources
    {
        public string resourceUri { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
        public Tags tags { get; set; }
    }

    public class Tags
    {
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string containerregistry { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string jsonString = "{'foo':{'Resources':{'resourceUri':'/xf/b/rs/RA-a-675e/fo/age/s/m78','location':'us','tags':{'displayName':'As storage','containerregistry':'dd'}}}}";

            var deserializedRootObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonString);

            System.Console.WriteLine(deserializedRootObject.foo.Resources.resourceUri);
            System.Console.WriteLine(deserializedRootObject.foo.Resources.location);
            System.Console.WriteLine(deserializedRootObject.foo.Resources.tags.displayName);
            System.Console.WriteLine(deserializedRootObject.foo.Resources.tags.containerregistry);
        }
    }
}
```